# Compare datasets and plot in sas

Tags: sas

I have two variables in 2 separate datasets in sas. Both have a primary key of Customer_Id and another column say LVR . One dataset has old values for the LVR Column. The other one has values from the new calculation for the same column.
I need to show the differences between both on a graph.

I tried to merge them and then tried proc gplot to plot the two LVRs.
Merged dataset looks something like this :
Cust_id LVR_new LVR_old
111     1       2
222     2       .
333     5       4
The dataset containing LVR_new is almost twice in size (number of rows) than the one containing LVR_old.We got more customers qualifying post the new calculations.
The merged dataset has 3046778 observations and 3 variables.
I tried to use proc gplot using the code below:

```
proc plot data=djia;
   plot LVR_old*LVR_new = Cust_id;
run;
```

This has been  running since long so i don't expect the results are going to be very useful.
Can anyone please suggest how can I achieve this. I need to showcase the differences between the two datasets on a graph to be able to show the shift in the results.
Thanks!

Comment: Please add a few records of sample data from each dataset, and show what code you have tried. You could merge the two datasets.  Might be easier to just concatenate them.  You could plot with a scatterplot, or a high-low plot, or compute the difference and plot that, or ...

Comment: Hi Quentin, My Data looks something like this:

Comment: Hi Quentin, My Data looks something like this: 
`Cust_id LVR_new LVR_old       
111     1       2
222     2       .
333     5       4`

This is the merged dataset. LVR_new and LVR_old are created in two separate datasets.
The dataset containing LVR_new is almost twice in size (number of rows) than the one containing LVR_old

I basically need to show the differences between these two datasets in a graphical form.
I tried to use proc gplot, but that's still running since the last hour. Do you have any suggestions on how can I achieve this?

Comment: apologies, couldn't format the sample table, just gets displayed on one line as inline code :-(

Comment: You should edit your question to show the sample data.  That will allow you to format it better.  Also edit your question to show the PROC GPLOT code you have tried. How large is the dataset?

Comment: Thanks I have updated my original question, please suggest of possible solutions.

Comment: I think you need a `QUIT;` for that to terminate. Your code is also PLOT, not GPLOT. Is there some reason you're not using SGPLOT?

Comment: I tried SGPLOT, and got this message in the log "SERIESPLOT statement has too many discrete values." May be plotting this type of data is not even possible.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use `PROC TTEST`?  There are some ODS GRAPHICS plots that PROC TTEST makes.

Your problem looks exactly liked the paired comparisons example in the documentation.
http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/statug/67523/HTML/default/viewer.htm#statug_ttest_examples03.htm

```
proc ttest;
  paired LVR_old*LVR_new;
run;
```